# Using a button and a menu item to call the same fragment (without creating duplicates in backStack)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am creating an application that has a drawer one MainActivity and many fragments one of the fragments holds all the buttons to the other fragments (excluding it self) so both the buttonsFragment and the drawer can call the fragments now the problem is that im creating two copies of each fragment when i call it from the drawer and when i call it from the buttonsFragment

My code:

MainActivity()

```
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    int id = item.getItemId();
    xFragment xFrag = new xfragment();

    if (id == R.id.menuItem1) {

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fM =     manager.beginTransaction();

        boolean moneyFragmentPoppedMenu = manager.popBackStackImmediate(xFragName,0);




        if(!FragmentPoppedMenu){

            fM.replace(R.id.content_main, xfrag, mT);
            fM.addToBackStack(mFragName);
            fM.commit();
        }

       else if (FragmentPoppedMenu){

        fM.replace(R.id.content_main, xfrag);}


    }
```

buttonsFragment()

```
xFragButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fM = manager.beginTransaction();
            boolean FragmentPoppedButton = manager.popBackStackImmediate(xFragName, 0 );


            if(!FragmentPoppedButton){
                fM.replace(R.id.content_main, xfrag);
                fM.addToBackStack(xFragName);
                fM.commit();
            }

         else  if (FragmentPoppedButton){ fM.replace(R.id.content_main, xfrag);}
```

I found out because when i open from menu and type something in an editText then open from buttonsFragment it shows a clear editText then when i open again from menu what i typed is still there

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle navigation view item clicks here.

int id = item.getItemId();
xFragment xFrag = new xfragment();

if (id == R.id.menuItem1) {
         xFragButton.performClick();

}
```

buttonsFragment:

onCreateView(){

```
Button xFragButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Button1);

xFragButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fM =     manager.beginTransaction();

    boolean moneyFragmentPoppedMenu = manager.popBackStackImmediate(xFragName,0);




    if(!FragmentPoppedMenu){

        fM.replace(R.id.content_main, xfrag, mT);
        fM.addToBackStack(mFragName);
        fM.commit();
    }

   else if (FragmentPoppedMenu){

    fM.replace(R.id.content_main, xfrag);
   }
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bader.myapplication/com.example.b.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

Comment: where do you have this xFragButton button? Please ensure it is not null.

Comment: bind xFragButton to it's view.or else post your onCreateView() code here

Comment: @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup       container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


 
            Button B1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Button1);

Comment: you have used XfragButton but here you are giving B1. please give a clear edited question. Edit your own question and paste the code there

Comment: I fixed it ... sorry for the confusion

Comment: But i don't see your changes?

Comment: I added the OncreateView() in buttonsFragment (maybe it needs time to show) where I created the button and then added a listener which is the same as in the head of the question, what did you mean bind the button to its view? the name of the button is xFragButton and id is Button1

Comment: well i cannot see your onCreateView()

Comment: my onCreateView() is exactly like what is showing under buttonsFragment

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bader.myapplication/com.example.b.‌​myapplication.MainAc‌​tivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

Comment: it is pointing to the declaration of the button in MainActivity()

Comment: okay then it could be the problem of Binding then. Button xFragButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Button1); remove v. in this line and try.

Comment: I cant because the button is in a fragment so I have to get it through the View this case its v

Comment: check for R.id.Button1 in the layout you bound to v.

Comment: it is the same id

Comment: so how can i call a button from a menu item?

Comment: Comment button thing and try